# IOS/objective-c: Convert unix time stamp string into NSDate format

Tags: ios, datetime

I am trying to get the current time in NSDate format.  I have been able to get the Unix timestamp to work, however, when I try to convert and format using an answer I found on SO, I get a null result.  Would appreciate any suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

Would also be interested in any more direct way to get the current date time in date time format i.e.... something like 2015-09-04 00:55:25 +0000

```
- (NSDate *) timeStampDate {
    //this returns time in string format
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
    NSLog(@"string:%@",string);//this prints fine
    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];
    NSLog(@"date%@",date);//this prints null
    return date;
/* this would go in opposite direction
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
    string = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
 */
}
```

Comment: Have you read *any* of the documentation for *any* of the date-related facilities of Objective-C???

Comment: That entire method body can be replaced with `return [NSDate date];`. If you simply want the current date as an `NSDate`, why are you doing so many unnecessary steps?

Comment: HotLicks  That is an obnoxious comment.  Of course I read the documentation.  Obnoxious hostile comments are contrary to the TOS for this site and if you have any integrity you should delete it.

Comment: rmaddy, nsdate date returns GMT.  I want local date time.  Not that that function does it.  Actually it returns null so there is something wrong with it...hence the question.

Comment: @user1904273 `NSDate date` returns the current date/time regardless of timezone. The displayed timezone is simply a display issue. BTW - precede a username with the `@` symbol when replying to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(NSDate*) timeStampDate {
    NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];

    return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:
        [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate: currentDate]
                          sinceDate: currentDate];
}
```